# License Intel Fortran compiler

Tags: matlab, fortran, intel-fortran

I am looking into compiling Fortran code in Matlab. The only supported compiler is apparently the Intel Fortan Composer. I am wondering whether there is a license for academic use that includes distributing files compiled with Intel Fortran Composer for academic use?

Comment: If the fortran code is going to be developed or maintained going forward, you could consider converting it to matlab source with f2matlab. One snag might be that you might have to optimize the m-file to get it to execute with similar performance as fortran.

Comment: That is certainly our intention. Perhaps we should look into easy ways to convert it to C++ code as well, since this is nor manageable to maintain..

Comment: A note: “supported complier” are those that they’re willing to help you with if stuff doesn’t work. If your compiler is not in the list, it doesn’t mean it will not work. Feel free to use the GCC Fortran compiler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is academic license available from Intel, just look in their e-shop or ask your local reseller. It is not free of charge, however. I am using compiler covered by this license every day. It should include also the binary redistribution, but much better place for questions like this is the [Intel Support Forums](http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-visual-fortran-compiler-for-windows)

Comment: As a student, you can also apply for student academic licenses, which are free of charge.
You should check https://software.intel.com/en-us/qualify-for-free-software/student for the conditions of applications.
Please, also note that IntelMPI and MKL have been open-sourced recently: https://software.intel.com/en-us/mpi-library/choose-download and https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl

Comment: @T.Gillis This is an old question with old answers, you may want to add a recent answer with the current situation. I assumed in my answer that the OP is a researcher like me, bet he could also be a student (back then).

Answer (score 2):

There is a non-commercial version of Intel's Fortran compiler for Linux: http://software.intel.com/en-us/non-commercial-software-development

I'm not too sure if that includes distribution of "academic" binaries - you'd better check the License agreement.

Comment: Thanks, for linux and mac matlab supports free compilers. On windows they don't seem to have non-commercial version. Thanks anyway

Comment: These are really only for **noncomercial** use, academic use does not qualify, because researchers and teachers are paid for the job.

Comment: Adding to what @VladimirF correctly states, it seems that there is no opening for academic **researchers**. They are paid for the job, thus they fall in the scope of commercial users. Additionally, if they are neither students nor educators nor contributors to open-source projects, so just researchers, there is no option free of charge immediately available to them. At least this is my current understanding, happy to be corrected. This FAQ item at Intel may provide some clarity and way out: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/non-commercial-software-faq/#14

Answer (score 0):

As of 2021, the Intel C++ and Fortran compilers are distributed via the [Intel oneAPI HPC Toolkit](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/tools/oneapi/hpc-toolkit.html) under the name "Intel C++ Compiler Classic"  and "Intel Fortran Compiler Classic".

Intel's [FAQ on commercial products support](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/troubleshooting/oneapi-commercial-faq.html) now states explicitly

> Are all of the oneAPI Toolkits available for free?
>
> Yes, all of the oneAPI Toolkits are available for free download and use for commercial and non-commercial purposes.

Intel says the oneAPI Toolkit [will remain free of charge, with support provided through community forums](https://twitter.com/IntelSupport/status/1275947112648376322?s=20&t=jX77Vaweey3sXizZZNy2Tw).

The [oneAPI Licensing Overview](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/license/end-user-license-agreement.html#collapseCollapsible1637778017303) even allows redistribution of the software:

> Use and Redistribution. You may use and redistribute the software (the
> "Software"), without modification, provided the following conditions
> are met:
>
> - Redistributions must reproduce the above copyright notice and the following terms of use in the Software and in the documentation and/or
>   other materials provided with the distribution.
> - Neither the name of Intel nor the names of its suppliers may be used to endorse or promote products derived from this Software without
>   specific prior written permission.
> - No reverse engineering, decompilation, or disassembly of this Software is permitted.

The times they are a-changin'...